# C++ Process Management

Tags: c++, boost, process, portability

Is there a well-known, portable, good library for C++ process management?

I found a promising library called [Boost.Process](http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process), but it's only a candidate for inclusion in the Boost library.  Has anyone use this? Does anyone know why it isn't a part of Boost?

Comment: what do you mean by project management?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh the help pages, especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much management do you need?  Just fork/exec?  IPC?  Resource management?  [Security contexts and process isolation](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox)?

I haven't used the Boost.Process library.  However, I do know that getting included in Boost is a rather difficult affair.  Boost recently accepted a futures library that had already been approved as part of the standard.  However, [getting into Boost wasn't a forgone conclusion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.announce/230).  Another library recently [did not make the cut](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.announce/229).  And although I think the criticisms are valid, I personally would be willing to use that library.

Answer (score 4):

There is a more modern version of Boost.Process (with incompatible changes) at

http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/

http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/process.zip

```
svn co http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/SOC/2010/process/boost
```

Although still not accepted to Boost, I use it a lot and works well for what I use it for. I am waiting to see this included in Boost one day.

**UPDATE 2019**: There is an accepted version of Boost.Process in Boost, but it incompatible with earlier versions mentioned above. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/process.html

See also: [Where is Boost.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process)