# Where is Boost.Process?

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, platform-independent, boost-process

I need to execute a program and retrieve its stdout output in c++. I'd like my code to be cross-platform too.

Having recently discovered the wonderful world of the Boost c++ libraries for all your cross platform needs, I figured I'd just go to boost.org and read up on the documentation of Boost.Process. Much to my surprise, it wasn't there! I then proceeded to figure out what name Boost gave their cross-platform library to start external processes, but haven't managed to find it so far.

A Google search brought me to Julio M. Merino Vidal's [Boost.Process](http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process/), which seems to be the unofficial Boost library I was looking for. Strangely enough, I cannot seem to find a download link on that website. It also seems like there haven't been any recent developments regarding the project.

I was finally able to find a download link for Vidal's Boost.Process on an [external site](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) and will use that for now, but I'm quite amazed at the effort I had to put in to get my hands on a cross platform c++ library to interact with external processes.

So, why is there no official Boost.Process? It seems like it would be a very valuable addition. Or am I totally overlooking the obvious solution here? Could you perhaps suggest other cross-platform libraries for managing simple starting of and interation with external processes?

Comment: Congratulations on the discovery -- Boost rocks!

Comment: Boost rocks, but there's no official Process library yet. For what it's worth, I successfully used the Poco Process library in the past (Google for the Poco C++ libraries for more information).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Julio M. Merino Vidal, who is, I beleive, the original author, wrote in [this 2007 post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/03/118196.php) that he did not have time to complete it.

Development was taken over by Boris Schaeling. This is the version that you found at http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/. According to this [post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2009/04/150688.php), he is still actively developing it.

There is another version, by [Ilya Sokolov](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/09/142538.php).

For your other question:

> Could you perhaps suggest other cross-platform libraries for managing simple starting of and interation with external processes?

you could look at [this wiki page](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?BoostProcess/ExistingLibraries) listing alternatives.

Depending on your needs, popen() could also do the job.

Comment: Just to complete information here, I would link the [review schedule](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html) in which is stated that boost.process has been [rejected](http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2011/03/0292.php).

Comment: This answer isn't up to date anymore, see the community wiki answer.

Answer (score 62):

Boost.Process was [accepted for inclusion into Boost on November 9, 2016](http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2016/11/0477.php); and [has been included in the 1.64](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_64_0.html) released on April 19, 2017. Boost.Process is now an official Boost library!

It's documentation is available here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html

---

For the record, the sources that were reviewed from October 27, 2016 through November 5, 2016 are available on GitHub:

download: https://github.com/klemens-morgenstern/boost-process

manual: http://klemens-morgenstern.github.io/process/index.html

---

You can find on the web several older versions of this library. They are all more or less incompatible:

- Version 0.5 (latest, as of 3rd Dec 2012)

download: http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/process.zip

manual: http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/index.html

- Version GSOC2010

download: http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/process.zip

manual: http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/

- Version 0.31

download: http://www.highscore.de/boost/process.zip

manual1: http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/

manual2: http://www.highscore.de/cpp/process/

I think it is the same as in http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/process/boost/

- I.S. Version 0.1-0.4

download: https://github.com/boost-vault/Process

- Version 0?

download: http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process.zip

manual: http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process/

There are other version that look like branches: https://github.com/JeffFlinn/boost-process and https://github.com/boost-vault/Process.

For a partial history of the project, look at http://www.highscore.de/cpp/process/#introduction

Answer (score 8):

Boost Process was one of the Google Summer of Code projects this year. The GSOC 2010 Boost Process website is http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/.

The library is still unofficial, but its developers feel that it is stable enough to [request formal review](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/10/171690.php).

Comment: It got rejected due to various concerns, I hope they will address those and resubmit.

Answer (score 8):

As of August 18th 2012, a newer version of Boost.Process (v0.5) has been released at http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/

hope that helps,
Philipp

Answer (score 4):

Another option might be the modularly designed [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), see [`Process::launch()`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Process.html#9431) which has an overload that takes [Pipes](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Pipe.html) for *in*, *out* and *error*.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Boost.Process is in the [sandbox area](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/process/), which would suggest that it has been proposed for inclusion and is probably still being work on, but hasn't been deemed stable, documented and/or useful enough to be included in the main boost release.

Answer (score 2):

For July 2015 it seems like `Boost.Process` has been [scheduled](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html) for the Boost formal review again.

Answer (score 1):

Parts of Boost.Process are available in several stand-alone libraries in Boost now: Boost.Interprocess, Program Options, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The new Boost Process is now in beta and will be available in Boost 1.64.0.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0_b2/doc/html/process.html