# Simplest way to interrupt a thread that is blocked on running a process

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to execute some commands via "/bin/sh" from a daemon. Some times these commands takes too long to execute, and I need to somehow interrupt them. The daemon is written in C++, and the commands are executed with std::system(). I need the stack cleaned up so that destructors are called when the thread dies. (Catching the event in a C++ exception-handler would be perfect).

The threads are created using boost:thread. Unfortunately, neither boost::thread::interrupt() or pthread_cancel() are useful in this case.

I can imagine several ways to do this, from writing my own version of system(), to finding the child's process-id and signal() it. But there must be a simpler way?

Comment: You may want to accept some answers to your **previous questions** before asking new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not try boost::process, as it is not part of boost. I did however try ACE_Process, which showed some strange behavior (the time-outs sometimes worked and sometimes did not work). So I wrote a simple std::system replacement, that polls for the status of the running process (effectively removing the problems with process-wide signals and alarms on a multi threading process). I also use boost::this_thread::sleep(), so that boost::thread::interrupt() should work as an alternative or in addition to the time-out.

Stackoverflow.com does not work very good with my Firefox under Debian (in fact, I could not reply at all, I had to start Windows in a VM) or Opera (in my VM), so I'm unable to post the code in a readable manner. My prototype (before I moved it to the actual application) is available here: http://www.jgaa.com/files/ExternProcess.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Any command executed using the `system` command is executed in a new process. Unfortunately system halts the execution of the current process until the new process completes. If the sub process hangs the new process hangs as well.

The way to get round this is to use `fork` to create a new process and call one of the `exec` calls to execute the desired command. Your main process can then `wait` on the child process's  Process Id (pid). The timeout can be achieve by generating a `SIGALRM` using the `alarm` call before the `wait` call.

If the sub process times out you can kill it using the `kill` command. Try first with `SIGTERM`, if that fails you can try again will `SIGKIL`L, this will certainly kill the child process.

Some more information on fork and exec can be found [here](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/pipeforkexec.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at Boost.Process:
[Where is Boost.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process)
I have been waiting for a long time for such a class.

If you are willing to use Qt, a nice portable solution is QProcess:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qprocess.html

Of course, you can also make your own system-specific solution like Let_Me_Be suggests.

Anyway you'd probably have to get rid of the system() function call and replace it by a more powerful alternative.