# Processes in boost

Tags: c++, boost, process

I'm using [boost.process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html) (additional lib for boost). At the page I gave for the link you can find samples of usage. I installed library, add: `#include <boost/process.hpp>` and some following code:

```
namespace bp = ::boost::processes; // In samples the namespace name is process!
bp::command_line temp("ls");

error: ‘command_line’ is not a member of ‘bp’
```

And I have such errors for all described samples. What's wrong?

---

I know that real namespace should be **process**, but I looked into the code and found that it's wrapped with `boost` and then `processes` namespaces. So there **aren't** any `process` namespace.

Comment: which sample are you trying to compile? I don't see `bp::command_line` referenced on the page you linked.

Comment: there are many different versions of boost.process, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12327853/225186. Make sure you are using a consistent documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not maybe using a different/older/alternate version of boost process i.e. did you get boost process from the [sandbox](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/process/boost/) recently? 
If you open up boost/process.hpp do you see the following at the top?

// Copyright (c) 2006, 2007 Julio M. Merino Vidal 
// Copyright (c) 2008, 2009 Boris Schaeling

I recall that there was another version of boost process by another author available in the past.

I had a look at some of the process files by Vidal/Schaeling and they definitely all use the boost::process namespace. If you do not see that in the source, you are prob using another version. Also, I did not see any entries for command_line in the reference available at http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/. FYI, boost process also went through numerous changes recently (following discussions on the boost mailing list).

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you say it yourself, the namespace from the samples is `::boost::process`. The line :

`namespace bp = ::boost::processes`

only defines a namespace alias : `bp::` is an alias for `boost::processes`. Writing `bp::command_line` is exactly like writing `boost::processes::command_line`. As `command_line` resides in the `boost::process` namespace, the type is not found.

Comment: @Ockonal: Sorry then, please ignore my answer. I'd like to help more, but I can't download boost.process from work T_T