# How to compile Boost.Process library?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction, bjam

So there is [Boost.Process 2006](http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process/), [Boost.Process 2008](http://www.boostpro.com/vault/index.php?direction=0&order=&directory=Process) and most recent [Boost.Process seems like 2009 by looking at sources)](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) I need some kind of step by step guidance on how to compile that beast. Because I deffenetly do not get how to do such thing.

So For generall official Boost I understand what shall be done

**With out administration privileges:**

- Download latest Boost release.
- Unpack, extract downloaded content into some folder.
- Open that folder in terminal (for example you ca open 'cmd' or 'terminal' an use command like `cd absolute/path/to/directory/with/extracted/Boost` than use command to show folder contents `ls` on Unix like OS (Mac, Linux) and `dir` on Windows - in output you should be capable to find `boost-build.jam` )
- Create two folders (using command like `mkdir` *foldername* ) `build-dir` and `install-dir`
- run command `./booststrap` (`booststrap.sh` or `booststrap.bat` on windows)
- now we can compile Boost and install it with `./bjam -j4 link=static  threading=single,multi --builddir=./build-dir install  --without-mpi --prefix=./install-dir`

  - Such call will compile static libraries of Boost into `build-dir`. (you probably will not be capable to use Boost out from there - there will be no includes headers and a really big directories hierarchy )
  - Than *bjam* will create for us "installation" of Boost into `install-dir` - there will appear folder with all boost libs (static version) and includes folder with all of boost headers.
  - We set -j4 flag to compile on 4 cores. use -j`N` where `N` is number of desired cores to be used during  compilation process.
  - We set `--without-mpi` flag because we probably do not use it.

But having Real Boost unpacked, compiled, installed in dir A (bjam is in folder B ) Having Boost.Process Download , Unpacked and Extracted to folder C how to compile any of that 3 Boost.Process releases (with out administration privileges)?

Comment: Not an answer, since it doesn't address how to build it, but there is certainly boost.process code more recent than 2009. At the least, the 2010 GSoC repository: http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/SOC/2010/process/

Comment: @ildjarn: well that one seems to be header only but it is deffenetly quite not up to date...

Comment: It's copyrighted 2010, which is more recent than any other sources I've seen.

Comment: Boost.Process 0.5, 2010GSOC and 0.31 don't need compilation, they are "header only". A list of version is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12327853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this once or twice and here's what I remember:

After downloading boost libs e.g. from the sandbox, unpack the lib onto the drive like you said e.g to folder C. If you open the C folder, it generally has the same folder structure as the rest of the boost source. At least this was the case in the limited libraries I tried.

From there copy the individual files and folders inside the extracted source folder into the corresponding folders in the boost source.

E.g. in the case of process 
- copy C/boost/process.hpp and C/boost/process/ to boost_src_dir/boost/
- copy C/libs/process/ to boost_src_dir/libs/.

From there execute bjam (assuming the bjam executable is on your path) again in the boost root and that in my cases built everything including the new library. I remember doing this with boost log and process and can't think of having to do anything else.

The downside to doing this is that everything gets recompiled. Perhaps someone else has a better method of doing this.

As for the admin priviledges, they shouldn't matter since you're building boost in the same manner that you built the original version.

Comment: Passing bjam e.g. `--with-process` should prevent the rest of boost from being rebuilt.

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks for that, will give it a try next time :)