# Is C++'s system() synchronized?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I'm writing a small utility which is supposed to launch several commands in parallel using `system()` and wait for their results for logging purposes. However, even though I'm calling `system()` on different threads, by looking at my Activity Monitor I only see one instance of each command at a time. It looks like system is internally synchronized on a mutex, and only one execution is allowed at each time, however this looks like a huge limitation, can someone confirm this behavior? Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

**Update** by looking at the threads execution flow, it looks like they're effectively synchronizing on a mutex. Is there an alternative `system()` which doesn't do that?

[image: threads]

I should mention I'm using C++11 (w/ clang and libc++) on Mac OS 10.7.5.

**Update** code is:

```
void Batch::run()
{
    done.clear();
    generator->resetGeneration();

    while(generator->hasMoreParameters())
    {
        // Lock for accessing active
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(q_mutex, adopt_lock);

        // If we've less experiments than threads
        if (active.size() < threads)
        {
            Configuration conf = generator->generateParameters();
            Experiment e(executable, conf);

            thread t(&Experiment::run, e, reference_wrapper<Batch>(*this));
            thread::id id = t.get_id();
            active.insert(id);
            t.detach();
        }

        // Condition variable
        q_control.wait(lock, [this] { return active.size() < threads; } );

    }
}

void Batch::experimentFinished(std::thread::id pos)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(q_mutex, adopt_lock);
    active.erase(pos);
    lock.unlock();
    q_control.notify_all();
}

void Experiment::run(Batch& caller)
{    
    // Generate run command
    stringstream run_command;
    run_command << executable + " ";
    ParameterExpression::printCommandLine(run_command, config);

    if (system(run_command.str().c_str()))
        stats["success"] = "true";
    else
        stats["success"] = "false";

    caller.experimentFinished(this_thread::get_id());
}
```

Just to be clear: the spawning and handling of threads works fine and does what it needs to do, but it looks like you can have just one instance of `system()` running at a time.

Thanks

Comment: Paste more codes please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To whoever comes later, `popen` did the trick, as it doesn't internally keep a mutex. The code to make it work is

```
FILE* proc;
char buff[1024];

// Keep track of the success or insuccess of execution
if (!(proc = popen(run_command.str().c_str(), "r")))
    stats["success"] = "false";
else
    stats["success"] = "true";

// Exhaust output
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), proc) != nullptr);

pclose(proc);
```

Comment: Nice. Still need to be sure you have nothing else that calls waitpid/waitid with a process selection parameter that includes the `popen`'d process, but that sounds like a great workaround.

Comment: Sure. However, I think I'm going to self-accept the answer for this time, since it is a possible solution of the explained problem.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX has this to say about [`system(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html):

> Using the system() function in more than one thread in a process or when the SIGCHLD signal is being manipulated by more than one thread in a process may produce unexpected results.

Due to the way that SIGCHLD must be blocked during the execution, running `system` calls concurrently doesn't really work. If you want multiple threads to run external tasks, you'll need to write a bit more code (handling `fork`/`exec`/`wait` yourself).

Comment: Can you suggest a solution in particular?

Comment: That's non-trivial, there's quite a bit of book-keeping you need to do, and doing it thread-safely could be tricky (see http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them for interesting issues). I'm not sure I'd know how to write that correctly, so I'd use a library and hope it got it right (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process).

Comment: I posted the solution that I used in an old program that I created below. It doesn't use multiple threads in the same process, it creates a new process via `fork`.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee: you should take a look at the first link in my comment.  The problem is doing the fork/exec/wait dance from multiple  threads which happens to get tricky pretty fast.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I included the disclaimer. I'm not recommending that it be used as-is in a multi-threaded program. It's more of an option in case multi-process can be used in place of multi-threaded. But I don't know much about the OP's use case.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps, I wrote some fork/exec/wait code in C++ a while back. It captures output into a `std::string`.

As @Mat points out, `fork`, `exec`, and `wait` aren't really designed to be uses in a [multi-threaded process](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them).

So this is more useful if multi-process can be a substitute for multi-threaded in your application.

```
bool Utility::execAndRedirect(std::string command, std::vector<std::string> args,     std::string& output, int& status)
{
    int error;
    int pipefd[2];
    int localStatus;

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        error = errno;
        cerr << "Executing command '" << command << "' failed: " << strerror(error) << endl;
        return false;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {       
        char** argsC;

        argsC = new char*[args.size() + 2];

        argsC[0] = new char[command.size() + 1];

        strncpy(argsC[0], command.c_str(), command.size());

        argsC[0][command.size()] = '\0';

        for (size_t count = 0; count < args.size(); count++)
        {
            argsC[count + 1] = new char[args[count].size() + 1];

            strncpy(argsC[count + 1], args[count].c_str(), args[count].size());

            argsC[count + 1][args[count].size()] = '\0';            
        }

        argsC[args.size() + 1] = NULL;

        close(pipefd[0]); 

        if (dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
        {
            error = errno;
            cerr << "Executing command '" << command << "' failed: " << strerror(error) << endl;
            exit(1);        
        }       

        if (dup2(pipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO) == -1)
         {
            error = errno;
            cerr << "Executing command '" << command << "' failed: " << strerror(error) << endl;
            exit(1);        
        }       

        close(pipefd[1]);

        if (execvp(command.c_str(), argsC) == -1)
        {
            error = errno;
            cerr << "Executing command '" << command << "' failed: " << strerror(error) << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];

        close(pipefd[1]);

        ostringstream oss;

        ssize_t num_b;

        while ((num_b = read(pipefd[0], buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0)
        {
            buffer[num_b] = '\0';

            oss << buffer;
        }

        output = oss.str();

        waitpid(pid, &localStatus, 0);

        close(pipefd[0]);
    }

    else
    {
        error = errno;
        cerr << "Executing command '" << command << "' failed: " << strerror(error) << endl;
        return false;   
    }

    if(WIFEXITED(localStatus))
    {
        status = WEXITSTATUS(localStatus);

        //DateTime current = DateTime::now(); //this is a custom class

        if(status == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
             return false;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        error = errno;
        cerr << "Executing command '" << command << "' failed: child didn't terminate normally" << endl;
        return false;   
    }   
}
```