# Process management code behaves different on Linux and Windows - Why?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, process, cross-platform

**(Context)** I'm developing a cross-platform (Windows and Linux) application for distributing files among computers, based on [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync). I've made it in C# already, and am now porting to C++ as an exercise.

BTSync can be started in [*API mode*](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/api), and for such, one must start the '*btsync*' executable passing the name and location of a config file as arguments.

At this point, my greatest problem is getting my application to deal with the executable. I've come to found [*Boost.Process*](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/) when searching for a cross-platform process management library, and decided to give it a try. It seems that v0.5 is it's latest working release, as [some evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process/12327853#12327853) suggests, and it can be infered there's a number of people using it.

I implemented the library as follows (relevant code only):

File: *test.hpp*

```
namespace testingBoostProcess
{
    class Test
    {
        void StartSyncing();
    };
}
```

File: *Test.cpp*

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/mitigate.hpp>
#include "test.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace testingBoostProcess;
namespace bpr = ::boost::process;

#ifdef _WIN32
const vector<wstring> EXE_NAME_ARGS = { L"btsync.exe", L"/config", L"conf.json" };
#else
const vector<string> EXE_NAME_ARGS = { "btsync", "--config", "conf.json" };
#endif

void Test::StartSyncing()
{
    cout << "Starting Server...";
    try
    {
        bpr::child exeServer = bpr::execute(bpr::initializers::set_args(EXE_NAME_ARGS),
            bpr::initializers::throw_on_error(), bpr::initializers::inherit_env());

        auto exitStatus = bpr::wait_for_exit(exeServer);    //  type will be either DWORD or int
        int exitCode = BOOST_PROCESS_EXITSTATUS(exitStatus);
        cout << " ok" << "\tstatus: " << exitCode << "\n";
    }
    catch (const exception& excStartExeServer)
    {
        cout << "\n" << "Error: " << excStartExeServer.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

**(Problem)** On Windows, the above code will start *btsync* and wait (block) until the process is terminated (either by using Task Manager or by the API's `shutdown` method), just like desired.
But on Linux, it finishes execution immediately after starting the process, as if `wait_for_exit()` isn't there at all, though the *btsync* process isn't terminated.

In an attempt to see if that has something to do with the *btsync* executable itself, I replaced it by this simple program:

File: *Fake-Btsync.cpp*

```
#include <cstdio>
#ifdef _WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define SLEEP Sleep(20000)
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define SLEEP sleep(20)
#endif
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf(argv[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    SLEEP;
    return 0;
}
```

When used with this program, instead of the original *btsync* downloaded from the official website, my application works as desired. It will block for 20 seconds and then exit.

**Question:** What is the reason for the described behavior? The only thing I can think of is that `btsync` restarts itself on Linux. But how to confirm that? Or what else could it be?

**Update:** All I needed to do was to know about what [forking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) is and how it works, as pointed in sehe's answer (thanks!).

**Question 2:** If I use the System Monitor to send an `End` command to the child process '*Fake-Btsync*' while my main application is blocked, `wait_for_exit()` will throw an exception saying:

> waitpid(2) failed: No child processes

Which is a different behavior than on Windows, where it simply says "ok" and terminates with status 0.

**Update 2:** sehe's answer is great, but didn't quite address Question 2 in a way I could actually understand. I'll write a new question about that and post the link here.

Comment: Take a look at Boost::Application https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application at least it's alive

Comment: @Sergey seems beyond what I want/need, but I'll see. Thanks!

Comment: The end process will still signal your process. Unless your program handles the signal, and exit nicely, it will be terminated with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your assumption about btsync. Let's start it:

```
./btsync 
By using this application, you agree to our Privacy Policy, Terms of Use and End User License Agreement.
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/privacy
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/terms-of-use
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/eula

BitTorrent Sync forked to background. pid = 24325. default port = 8888
```

So, that's the whole story right there: **`BitTorrent Sync forked to background`**. Nothing more. Nothing less. If you want to, `btsync --help` tells you to pass `--nodaemon`.

### Testing Process Termination

Let's pass `--nodaemon` run `btsync` using the test program. In a separate subshell, let's kill the child `btsync` process after 5 seconds:

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ (./test; echo exit code $?) & (sleep 5; killall btsync)& time wait
[1] 24553
[2] 24554
By using this application, you agree to our Privacy Policy, Terms of Use and End User License Agreement.
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/privacy
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/terms-of-use
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/eula

[20141029 10:51:16.344] total physical memory 536870912 max disk cache 2097152
[20141029 10:51:16.344] Using IP address 192.168.2.136
[20141029 10:51:16.346] Loading config file version 1.4.93
[20141029 10:51:17.389] UPnP: Device error "http://192.168.2.1:49000/l2tpv3.xml": (-2) 
[20141029 10:51:17.407] UPnP: ERROR mapping TCP port 43564 -> 192.168.2.136:43564. Deleting mapping and trying again: (403) Unknown result code (UPnP protocol violation?)
[20141029 10:51:17.415] UPnP: ERROR removing TCP port 43564: (403) Unknown result code (UPnP protocol violation?)
[20141029 10:51:17.423] UPnP: ERROR mapping TCP port 43564 -> 192.168.2.136:43564: (403) Unknown result code (UPnP protocol violation?)
[20141029 10:51:21.428] Received shutdown request via signal 15
[20141029 10:51:21.428] Shutdown. Saving config sync.dat
Starting Server... ok   status: 0
exit code 0
[1]-  Done                    ( ./test; echo exit code $? )
[2]+  Done                    ( sleep 5; killall btsync )

real    0m6.093s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.026s
```

No problem!

### A Better Fake Btsync

This should still be portable and be (much) better behaved when killed/terminated/interrupted:

```
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service is;
    boost::asio::signal_set ss(is);
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(is, boost::posix_time::seconds(20));
    ss.add(SIGINT);
    ss.add(SIGTERM);

    auto stop = [&]{ 
        ss.cancel();    // one of these will be redundant
        timer.cancel();
    };

    ss.async_wait([=](boost::system::error_code ec, int sig){ 
            std::cout << "Signal received: " << sig << " (ec: '" << ec.message() << "')\n"; 
            stop();
        });
    timer.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code ec){
            std::cout << "Timer: '" << ec.message() << "'\n";
            stop();
        });

    std::copy(argv, argv+argc, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    is.run();

    return 0;
}
```

You can test whether it is well-behaved

```
(./btsync --nodaemon; echo exit code $?) & (sleep 5; killall btsync)& time wait
```

The same test can be run with "official" `btsync` and "fake" `btsync`. Output on my linux box:

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ (./btsync --nodaemon; echo exit code $?) & (sleep 5; killall btsync)& time wait
[1] 24654
[2] 24655
./btsync
--nodaemon
Signal received: 15 (ec: 'Success')
Timer: 'Operation canceled'
exit code 0
[1]-  Done                    ( ./btsync --nodaemon; echo exit code $? )
[2]+  Done                    ( sleep 5; killall btsync )

real    0m5.014s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.014s
```

Comment: Btw, could you elaborate on whether the behavior described on *Question 2* is wrong? I simply didn't/don't know enough about the [Fork syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29), but Wikipedia says: "When a child process terminates before the parent has called wait, the kernel retains some information about the process, such as its exit status, to enable its parent to call wait later" [(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process#End_of_life), and thus, I think `wait_for_exit()` should work.

Comment: @Marc.2377 The behaviour is correct, your assumption incorrect. `wait_for_exit()` waits for the child process to exit, not for any grand-children. `btsync` in daemon spawns a child process (detached from console and potentially privilege-separated) and then the parent exits. Therefore, `wait_for_exit()` unblocks.

Comment: *Question 2* is actually about my "Fake-Btsync", my version (the one which sleeps for 20 seconds)...