# Running C++ program and Notepad

Tags: c++, notepad

How to open a notepad in C++ then still continue using the c++ program even when the notepad is open? I tried system("filename.txt") But I can't continue using the c++ program unless I close the notepad file. is this possible?

Comment: Not possible portably. Each OS is going to need different code. Looks like Boost has a library for it, as usual, or at least almost in this case, as it's [not quite in there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process).

Comment: Spawn a thread and open the editor from there. But chances are, once you're looking at `system()` in your C/C++ code, your program is FUBAR anyway. There are only very few meaningful use cases for `system()`, and I have not really come across one yet in the wild. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't write on what OS you're on but on windows you can use

```
system("start notepad.exe");
```

for example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void){

    system("start notepad.exe");
    std::string x;
    std::cin>>x;
    std::cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

the trick is the "start" command rather then just the filename

Comment: -1 for system(). Causes a lot of trouble including potential security vulnerability, unintended behavior and program possibly being recognized as a virus.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", _T("notepad.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```