# Redirecting output from child processes

Tags: c++, macos, uwp, window, createprocess

In my c++ windows app I start multiple child processes and I want them to inherit parent's stdout/stderr, so that if output of my app is redirected to some file then that file would also contain output of all child processes that my app creates.

Currently I do that using CreateProcess without output redirection. MSDN has a sample how to redirect output: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx), but I want to see what alternative do I have. Simplest is to use system and call it from a blocking thread that waits for child to exit. All output is then piped back to parent's stdout/stderr, however in parent process I do not have a chance to process stdout data that comes from child.
There are also other functions to start processes on windows: [spawn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx), [exec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w.aspx), which might be easier to port to posix systems.

What should I use if I want it to work on linux/osx? What options do I have if I want it to work on [UWP aka WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)? I might be totally ok with `system` called from a blocking thread, but perhaps I'd prefer to be able to have more control on process PID (to be able to terminate it) and process stdout/stderr, to prepend each line with `child##:` for example.

Comment: Is it completely necessary to use stdin/stdout/stderr - would other file descriptors be enough? Can you explain your constraints? Perhaps write your program to use the stdout of another command in the shell pipe way ( e.g. cat file | less ). You can then use the tee command line program (on Linux) to capture the output of one program to a file and still allow it to be consumed by the next program in the pipe chain?

Comment: For cross-platform have a look at [boost::process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12327853/7571258), which apparently has been accepted to boost but not included in an official release yet. Tutorial has an [example](http://klemens-morgenstern.github.io/process/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io) how to forward output from one process to another.

Comment: @zett42 I know about `boost::process`, AFAIK the author didn't have time to complete it to make it part of boost. I doubt that it supports windows uwp though for obvious reasons. In my case, we try to distance ourselves from `boost`, as our compile times and overall build size taken by objects in just too big already. This isn't really boost issue though, that's C++ itself.

Comment: @JimmyNJ In my case I was starting a child process and complete discarded its output. I want to update my code so that output from children goes the same place where output of my app goes. I need only stdout/stderr, nothing else. Starting children with stdout/stderr redirected to a file that my app later could read when child exists is one of possibilities, I didn't think about it, but I think I'd rather redirect stdout/stderr from children rather than using intermediate files. My child processes run for some time and with files I'd get output too late.

Comment: [Github page](https://github.com/klemens-morgenstern/boost-process) states `boost::process` will propably be included in boost 1.64. Seems to be quite active, last commits few days ago.

Comment: @Pavel, I see. I wish I could help promptly but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boost libraries recently released version 1.64 which includes a new `boost::process` library.

In it, you're given a C++ way to be able to redirect output to a pipe or `asio::streambuf`, from which you can create a `std::string` or `std::istream` to read whatever your child process wrote.

You can read up on [`boost::process` tutorials here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html), which shows some simple examples of reading child output. It does make heavy use of `boost::asio`, so I highly recommend you [read up on that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) too.

Comment: I used boost process for a very long time (it's been there not completely finished for 10 years probably). The project that I work on is stuck on boost 1.58 and I cannot bring in other libraries, so have to do all that IPC manually. I ended up writing popen2-like code