# Is std::system or exec better practice?

Tags: c++

I have a program that calls a shell script tool that I made that goes through a directory and zips up files and gets the checksum value and calls some other tools to upload the files. The operation takes roughly 3 to 4 minutes.

I call the script like this:

```
int result = system("/bin/sh /path/to/my/script");
```

I've also got the same result by using the `exec()` family of functions:

```
int child = fork();
if(child == 0) {
    execl( "/bin/sh", "sh", "/path/to/my/script", (char*)0 );
}
```

I know with `exec` you can redirect output to the parent program so it can read the output of the command line tools, but other than that when should you use `system` as opposed to `exec`?

Comment: Note that one is portable, the other is not.

Comment: But it is hard to find an *argument* to `system` which is portable. `"/bin/sh ..."` certainly is not going to be portable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ignoring for the time being that use of `system` is portable while use of `exec` family of functions is not portable...

When you combine use of `exec` family of functions with other POSIX functions such as `pipe`, `dup`, `wait`, you get a lot more control over how to pass data between the parent process and the child process.

When you don't need any of those controls, i.e. you just want to execute a command, then using `system` is preferable, IMO.

Comment: Mostly agree. However, purely anecdotally, I prefer to have a properly flexible `popen` wrapper (e.g. [Boost.Process](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1683665/560648)) to hand and use that for basically everything. My only problem with that is that Boost.Process is, for some reason, a compilation-time killer. Works nicely though.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, does that wrapper work with MS VC++? If so, I would love to get my hands on it.

Comment: Click on the link and find out! But I have no reason to believe that the answer is no.

Comment: So from your response I guess the general rule of thumb is to keep it as simple as possible for portability and readability.

Answer (score 1):

The first `system` call in your question will do the same, what you are doing in the next piece of code (fork and execl)

From documentation:

```
 The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process
 that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3)
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html

Comment: This is wrong. There is no reason for  system() to use fork(), and system() is available on platforms that don't support it, for example, Windows.

Comment: True.. but his question is specific to linux or some unix like systems as he is using "fork" and "execl"

Comment: Answering with Linux-only facts (and not even disclosing their platform-specific nature) to a question asking for best practice seems kind of dishonest.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes I agree.... but seeing "fork" and "execl", I am inclined to Unix like systems..... And also earlier when I gave some answers for cross platform..... I was beaten to death ....... saying, where did you see windows in question.... :)

Comment: Yeah, so, you missed the point. The point is that the best practice is to _not_ use `fork` or `execl`, so that you _can_ share the code on Windows (and other non-Linux platforms). Instead, you assumed that the Linux approach will be used, to the extent that your answer makes Linux-specific assumptions while discussing `system`, ignoring and not mentioning that actually your answer is platform-specific too.