# Multiprocessing in Boost?

Tags: boost, process, fork, multiprocessing

I need to create processes in a cross platform way.

I noticed that boost::process is not included in Boost, yet, and its last update is more than two years old. Is it a good idea to use it, or could it be a forgotten utility not worth considering?

Are there alternatives still inside Boost?

Thank's.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065054/c-process-management

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process

Comment: robert: I saw those questions. The fact is that they are two years old, and I was wandering if things have evolved in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a research I've did , boost.process "cutting edge" can be found [here](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/index.html) (please note Copyright © 2006-**2012**) 
It includes the bread & butter of process management (stream redirection, PATH env variable search.) IMO more machinery should be added (e.g. bounded wait for process termination) yet it worth usage consideration :)